# How do I use the Test::Unit::TestCase Perl CPAN module?

Tags: perl, cpan, perl-module

I have the following file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Test::Unit::TestCase;
$self->assert(1)
```

and when I run `test.pl` I get the following:

```
Can't call method "assert" on an undefined value at ./parse.pl line 3.
```

I ran `sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Test::Unit'` and the module seemed to be installed correctly (especially since I get no error on the `use` statement), but I don't know how to actually use the module.

Comment: It's just telling you that `$self` is undefined.

Comment: Check the example in the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~mcast/Test-Unit-0.25/lib/Test/Unit/TestCase.pm)

Comment: What @Klaus said, and don't forget to `use strict; use warnings;` to get more explanations about why Perl is unhappy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try copying the code sample from the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Test%3a%3aUnit%3a%3aTestCase)? (see `perldoc Test::Unit::TestCase` on the command line.)

Your first problem that you are getting warnings about is that `$self` has not been initialized.  A second problem is that you are not using strict, which would have given you a clearer warning.  A third problem is that you are not inheriting from the module.  The code sample in the documentation will solve the first and third problems, and the second is something that should become a habit.

Comment: The main problem is that the OP does not seem to know Perl at all.

Comment: This is true :). Thanks for the assistance. Once I figured out that I can use the TestRunner (http://search.cpan.org/~clemburg/Test-Unit-0.14/lib/Test/Unit/TestRunner.pm) to actually run the tests I make, things also made more sense.